# android dialog with list and imageview

Tags: android, dialog, android-imageview, textview

I am new to android. I have a layout that contains an imageview and a textview. I also have a list that contains some data information.

I would like to add the list in the dialog on the textview position. Imageview is set to a default image and I would like to leave it like that for the momenet. Later i will have a new list with imageview that I would like to set to my imageview from the layout.view pos.

I would like to ask how to set the list data to the textview and also how to obtain the clicked element from the dialog
I don't know how to add the list in the dialog on the text

```
builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getApplicationContext());
LayoutInflater li = (LayoutInflater) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);  
View promptsView = li.inflate(R.layout.contact_filster_list,(ViewGroup) findViewById(R.id.layout_root));
builder.setView(promptsView);
final ImageView userInput = (ImageView) promptsView.findViewById(R.id.dialog_icon);
final TextView userInput1 = (TextView) promptsView.findViewById(R.id.dialog_text);
```

Comment: Take a look to use custom list view. http://www.mkyong.com/android/android-listview-example/ .And you can use builder.setAdapter() to set custom list view to Alert Dialog.

Comment: can you post your contact_filster_list layout xml file

Comment: and as a sidenote: you should change `getApplicationContext()` to be `YourActivityName.this`. You will avoid potential memory leaks by doing so.